# Подгрузка джавы из другого пути

Tags: java

Как сделать так,чтобы java подгружалась к примеру не из дефолтного пути

> C:/Program Files/Java/jre 1.8

а по пути, например:

> D:/Test/Java/jre 1.8 ?

Comment: Это зависит от того как и где вы запускаете приложение. Из IDE будет один вариант, из эксплорера другой, из командной строки третий.

Comment: Я запускаю лаунчер(написан на С++)после прогрузки,он подгружает jav'у из не стандартного пути и лаунчер написанный на java

Comment: Тогда только автору лаунчера ведома логика поиска java в системе.

Comment: Укажи в переменных среды путь к джаве(если работаешь в винде)